# Why ListView been updated when i setState to something else?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a ListView in my page,and its dataSouce is this.state.ds
And i have something else in this.state which has no relationship with this ListView.
But everytime when I setState({ somethingelse:xx}),the ListView always get rerendered and the textInput in ListView's item was clear.

I'm very confused with this and is something about RN principle I understood is wrong?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a `rowHasChanged` function?

From [ListView docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html):

> Only re-render changed rows - the rowHasChanged function provided to
>   the data source tells the ListView if it needs to re-render a row
>   because the source data has changed - see ListViewDataSource for more
>   details.

Could be as simple as:

```
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
this.state = {
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([...]),
};
```

Comment: I use the same rowHasChanged function as you mentioned.

Comment: I use the same rowHasChanged function as you mentioned. And i found that rowHasChanged was called only when I changed the dataSource, which was as I expected. But the listItem's render() was called when I call setState to 'somethingElse',which was out of my expection.

Comment: @user6594603 You'll have to update your question with more of your code or it's hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` always triggers the `render()` function again which causes your ListView to refresh basically.

if you don't want that to happen you can declare `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

Depending on when you want `setState` to cause a re-render or not, `shouldComponentUpdate()` function should return true or false.

example of how you do it:

```
var shouldRender = true;

shouldComponentUpdate(){

return this.shouldRender;
} 

   myFunction(){
   ....
   this.shouldRender=false;
   ...
   this.setState({key:value});
   ...
   this.shouldRender=true;
}
```

you should also note that setState is not synchronous therefore, setting state using the above function might still cause a re-render a better version would be to do this:

```
var shouldRender = true;

shouldComponentUpdate(){

   return this.shouldRender;
} 

myFunction(){
   ....
   this.shouldRender=false;
   ...
   that=this;
   this.setState({key:value},function(){
       that.shouldRender=true;
   });
   ...
}
```

checkout more about `setState`:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate